# Viewbag not working when generated by JS innerhtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, viewbag

I am generating HTML using JS innerhtml. The html is a select input with data from a Viewbag. When the select is generated there are no elements in it.

The exact same select input works if not generated by innerhtml.

```
for (i = 1; i <= memberCount; i++) {
        fullMemberHTML +=
        (
            '<div class="dropdown">' +
            '<select asp-for="Name" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Name" id="umaModelSelection" onchange="updatePercentages()"><option value="none">Select one</option></select>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }

    document.getElementById("memberInfo").innerHTML = fullMemberHTML;
```

When I run the generated HTML by JS innerhtml, the select shows up but with only one content. I am trying to get it to populate using the Viewbag.Name contents.

Please note the select gets the Viewbag contents if not generated by JS innherhtml

Thank you for all your help

Comment: what is the value of your `memberCount` ? you are concatenating all the texts inside your loop, no variables to dynamically add further `option` in the `select` tag, so it's happening. if you want to dynamically add `option`s in your `select` you need to use your variables related to accordingly

Comment: memberCount can be any user input value. I know there are no dynamically made variable names at this point. I was trying to illustrate how this innerHtml does not pick up the ViewBag.Name items to populate the select list.

Comment: if you expect to `asp-items="ViewBag.Name"` to generate some values, it won't, because it's simply a text inside a `""` mark, you need to separate it out of a sting, then it might be treated as a dynamic JS token

Comment: ViewBag is serverside, where js is client side. They have no knowledge of each other without you explicitly assigning a js variable with the ViewBag data eg 
`var someJsVariable = '@ViewBag.Name';` and then use that data in the select. However this is **bad practice**, you should rework your solution to rather use asp.net core razor syntax with tag helpers if possible: `@for (var i = 1; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++) { <select asp-items="@ViewBag.Name" /> }`